# Why and how ulem package disable linebreaking and stretching encountering brace and macro replacement

Tags: context, soul, underline, ulem

**Descriptions of my questions**

So, I am doing some hacking which requires me to use `ulem` package. I found on page 5 of the documentation of this package (dated 2019/11/18) that

> One important incompatibility with braces and macro replacement: All the text in braces or coming from a macro is typeset in a box (as if in \mbox). Consequently, braces will suppress stretching and line-breaking in the text they enclose

I'm very unpleasant with this functionality and thus have the following questions

1. Why do they have to introduce this kind of functionality?
2. How do they realize this kind of functionality? More specifically, I want to learn which code in their source code `ulem.sty` introduce this kind of functionality.
3. Little aside. I find that functionalities like underline and highlight are all very hard to use in `LaTeX`. By hard, I mean that either the existing solutions possess many defects, or we have to do some hard hacking to realize it. For example, this unpleasant feature of `ulem` described here. Or the infamout `Reconstruction failed` when using `soul`. But, in other markup languages, it would be very easy to use. For example, in `HTML` and `Markdown`, one just uses `<u>` tag. In `ConTeXt` one can use [`\definetextbackground`](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/TextBackground). Both are easy to use. So, what makes the underline feature so difficult to realize in `LaTeX`? **Attention that here I'm not ask why people should avoid using underline from the typographic side. I'm asking which unerlying coding mechanism prevent underline so difficult to realize.**

**MWE if that help**

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}


\begin{document}
    % \ul{\lipsum[1]}  % the infamous Reconstruction failed error

    % \ul{\href{www.google.com}{Google}}  % also some other error

    % \ul{\url{www.google.com}}  % also some other error

    \ul{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque dictum enim neque, non interdum diam vulputate et. Maecenas rhoncus vel libero vitae auctor. Pellentesque nec nisl sed nisi egestas tristique. Donec in semper tellus, sit amet pellentesque est. Sed scelerisque risus ut orci interdum convallis. Quisque placerat vehicula malesuada. Vestibulum est libero, pretium sit amet turpis vel, vulputate rhoncus nibh. Proin dictum lacus ut enim finibus tempus. Praesent malesuada viverra faucibus. Aliquam nisi risus, eleifend vel lorem a, porttitor molestie nunc. Phasellus porta urna sit amet tellus euismod, vitae aliquet augue commodo. Etiam congue bibendum enim. Donec congue dignissim massa, eget sodales erat tristique eu. Donec a diam vel eros vestibulum eleifend. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Duis id gravida nulla.}  % normal

    \uline{\lipsum[1]}  % by macro replacement, no line break

    \uline{{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque dictum enim neque, non interdum diam vulputate et. Maecenas rhoncus vel libero vitae auctor. Pellentesque nec nisl sed nisi egestas tristique. Donec in semper tellus, sit amet pellentesque est. Sed scelerisque risus ut orci interdum convallis. Quisque placerat vehicula malesuada. Vestibulum est libero, pretium sit amet turpis vel, vulputate rhoncus nibh. Proin dictum lacus ut enim finibus tempus. Praesent malesuada viverra faucibus. Aliquam nisi risus, eleifend vel lorem a, porttitor molestie nunc. Phasellus porta urna sit amet tellus euismod, vitae aliquet augue commodo. Etiam congue bibendum enim. Donec congue dignissim massa, eget sodales erat tristique eu. Donec a diam vel eros vestibulum eleifend. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Duis id gravida nulla.}}  % extra brace, also no line break

    \uline{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque dictum enim neque, non interdum diam vulputate et. Maecenas rhoncus vel libero vitae auctor. Pellentesque nec nisl sed nisi egestas tristique. Donec in semper tellus, sit amet pellentesque est. Sed scelerisque risus ut orci interdum convallis. Quisque placerat vehicula malesuada. Vestibulum est libero, pretium sit amet turpis vel, vulputate rhoncus nibh. Proin dictum lacus ut enim finibus tempus. Praesent malesuada viverra faucibus. Aliquam nisi risus, eleifend vel lorem a, porttitor molestie nunc. Phasellus porta urna sit amet tellus euismod, vitae aliquet augue commodo. Etiam congue bibendum enim. Donec congue dignissim massa, eget sodales erat tristique eu. Donec a diam vel eros vestibulum eleifend. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Duis id gravida nulla.}  %normal

    \uline{\href{www.google.com}{Google}}  % work fine

    \uline{\url{www.google.com}}  % work fine

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your MWE is a LaTeX document. You won't compile it with `context`. You should delete the `context` tag.

Comment: @sztruks the question asks (amongst other things) why this is hard in latex when context can do it so I don't think the context tag is necessarily wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any tex primitive for drawing a rule or underlining is going to make an unbreakable box, so `ulem` and `soul` have to go to a lot of work adding multiple boxes around each part of the input to try to underline without losing breakpoints, doing this while considering hyphenation and arbitrary nested tex commands is hard and it's not surprising there are restrictions.

context of course is luatex-only, and with lualatex you may prefer the `lua-ul` package that can access things at a lower level using Lua so use facilities that are not available in classic tex.

Comment: ConTeXt MkII (pdftex engine) also supports underline which breaks across lines (but does not hyphenate). I added an answer to illustrate that.

Answer (score 0):

I was intrigued by David's comment on how much of context's handling is due to the engine. So, I tried this simple example:

```
\setuppapersize[A6]

\define\lipsum%
  {\dosingleargument\dolipsum}

\def\dolipsum[#1]%
  {Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque dictum enim neque, non interdum diam vulputate et. Maecenas rhoncus vel libero vitae auctor. Pellentesque nec nisl sed nisi egestas tristique. Donec in semper tellus, sit amet pellentesque est. Sed scelerisque risus ut orci interdum convallis. Quisque placerat vehicula malesuada. Vestibulum est libero, pretium sit amet turpis vel, vulputate rhoncus nibh. Proin dictum lacus ut enim finibus tempus. Praesent malesuada viverra faucibus. Aliquam nisi risus, eleifend vel lorem a, porttitor molestie nunc. Phasellus porta urna sit amet tellus euismod, vitae aliquet augue commodo. Etiam congue bibendum enim. Donec congue dignissim massa, eget sodales erat tristique eu. Donec a diam vel eros vestibulum eleifend. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Duis id gravida nulla.}  

\showframe

\starttext
\underbar{\input knuth\relax}

\underbar{\lipsum[1]}
\stoptext
```

I am creating a fake `\lipsum` command which is unexpandable to mimic what is happening in LaTeX.

With ConTeXt MkII (i.e., the pdftex engine), I get the following output (only pasting page 1). Note that the underline works, but there is no hyphenation.

[image]

With ConTeXt MkIV (i.e., the luatex engine) and ConTeXt LMTX (i.e., the luametatex engine), I get the following output (underline works and there is hyphenation:

[image]

I don't remember how underline in MkII is implemented (MkII has been deprecated for over a decade now), but it is possible to have line breaks for underlined text in pdftex (at the cost of hyphenation).